# Как за хешировать Cookies без повторения хеша

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Хеширую куки, но получается одинаковый хэш, хотя все строки разные.

```
(string) $server_name = hash("sha512", $_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]);

if($server_name != null) {
    setcookie("domain", $server_name);
    echo("$server_name");
}

(string) $ip = hash("sha512", $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]);

if($ip != null) {
    setcookie("IP", $ip);
    echo("$ip");
}
```

Comment: Что за жуткий алгоритм - `sha521`? И зачем вы хешируете `$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]` и `$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]`? Думаете о их содержимом ни кто не догадается из названия кук? Алгоритмы хеширования можете посмотреть тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.hash-algos.php

Comment: Спасибо что нашел ошибку в коде sha512 вместо sha521

Comment: Все делаю по философии нельзя хранить донные на компьютере пользователя в открытом виде потомушто пользователь всегда скомпремитивен. В общем хеширую для безопастости

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете данную концепцию.

Comment: @AntonLoginov ну да, пользователь просто поменяет ваш хэш сервера/айпишника на хэш любого другого сервера/айпишника ;)

Comment: Так ip пользователя, Хеш Домена сервера. при замене пользователем ip и domain если $COOKIE["IP"]... ТУ-ТУ-ТУ... :)                                                       Так мы отошли от темы как захешировать переменную $ip и $server_name и чтобы все это несоздовало одинаковый хеш

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ступил, код приведенный в вопросе работает правильно.